# Calling .net dll from php on shared hosting

Tags: php, .net, dll, shared-hosting

Is there a way to call a .net DLL from php on a shared hosting system (either on windows or linux)

I don't have root access or the ability to register the DLL as a com object so calling DOTNET(), COM(), SHELL_EXEC() or variants are kind of out.  Any ideas on a relatively cheap way to accomplish this?

Comment: Get access to dotnet.  You need to.  Get a VPS, if you cannot afford your own box.

Comment: I have access to .net ... it's a ASP.net host.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.
if you cannot access those function, you cannot call .net dll.